# alternate ways to typedef structs

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a way to typedef a templatized struct in C++? For instance something like:

```
template <typename T>
struct mylist
{
  std::vector<T> contents;
  // ... other members
};

typedef struct mylist<T> * List<T>; // this is illegal
```

My goal is to hide the fact that my `List` is a pointer such that I can write code like:

```
List<int> intList;
List<char> charList;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [alias template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) (since C++11). E.g.

```
template <typename T>
using List = mylist<T> *;
```

Then

```
List<int> intList;   // -> mylist<int> *
List<char> charList; // -> mylist<char> *
```

Comment: fwiw, I would suggest to name it properly, eg `ListPtr`. A pointer to a list isnt a list